# How add to ajax request additional GET params in django-ajax-select?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-ajax-selects

I need sent parametr *`region`* with ajax request in select.

[Select sending ajax without additional parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjoCs.png)

`@register('address')
class TagsLookup(LookupChannel):

```
model = Address

def get_query(self, q, request):

    **region = request.GET.get('region')**

    region_null = '__'.join([region, 'isnull'])
    return list(self.model.objects
             .filter(**{region_null: False})
             .exclude(**{f'{region}': ''})
             .exclude(**{f'{region}': ' '})
             .order_by(f'{region}')
             .values_list(f'{region}', flat=True).distinct())

def format_item_display(self, item):
    return u"<span class='tag'>%s</span>" % item.city`
```

Send region GET parametw with django-ajax-select request.
Their documentation says the following:

[django-ajax-select documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Ac2.png)